# Parameter for upper and lower bound in linear programming solvers

Tags: matlab, scipy, linear-programming, dolphindb

Many scientific computing platforms provide a linear programming solver. For example, there is a `linprog` function in MATLAB, Scipy, and DolphinDB. And `linprog` in all those three platforms provides a parameter for inequality constraints, namely `A`, and two parameters for bounded variables, namely `lb` and `ub`.

If a linear programming problem has bounded variables, I could place them in the inequality constraints, `A`, by adding a row containing only one `1` or `-1` with the remaining elements being `0`, or alternatively I could simply place them in `lb` and/or `ub`.

Is there any difference between those two ways? Or is there any reason that I should favor `A` over `lb`/`ub`, or vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bounds are a little bit more efficient than explicit constraints. Basically, in a Simplex solver, a bound does not increase the size of the basis matrix. This basis matrix needs to be solved and inverted (factorized).

Advanced solvers have a presolver that will convert singleton constraints into bounds. In that case there is no real performance penalty. For those solvers it is mostly a question of taste how to specify bound constraints: as a bound or as a singleton constraint.